# Widget iOS 14 create the ui with react native using swift ui

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native, swiftui

Widget example in iOS:

[image]

Example of the react-native(js) code written below:

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var Widget = NativeModules.Widget;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Widget>
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#dee1e3',
          borderRadius: 4,
        }}>
        <Text>San Francisco</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>62°F</Text>
      </View>
    </Widget>
  );
};

export default App;
```

There is still not much documentation on creating widgets with `Swift ui` for `iOS 14`.

It wouldn't seem that difficult to create a widget using `Swift ui`, but there isn't much information.

So I thought it would be interesting to develop the ui using `react-native` and use `swift ui` just to create the widget for `iOS`.

Idea is this, everything inside the tag (let's call it that) `<Widget>` (hence its child) should be the content of the `Widget`.

I did not find anything in the documentation, I was wondering exists in `Swift ui` or something for `iOS`, to use child content as `UI` for app.

Surely such a thing will be impossible, but dreaming costs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only possibility is to create the Widget native in SwiftUI. Probably in the future https://github.com/react-native-community will create an extension to support iOS Widgets with React-Native.

I've created a small library to support the functionality of WidgetKit. https://github.com/fasky-software/react-native-widgetkit

In combination with https://medium.com/groww-engineering/adding-widget-for-react-native-app-in-ios-14-with-swiftui-fd04ff181d33 you should be able to create a widget with a RN App :)

Comment: Hi, could you please explain this step by step?

Comment: Do I need to install this plugin only or is there any changes I have to make it running?

Answer (score 0):

**What you can do is**

1. clean the project.
2. make sure it's running correctly without adding widget
3. Follow the picture

[image: what to edit]

4. in the library search paths, change 5.0 to 5.2

`"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`

To

`"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.2/$(PLATFORM_NAME)"`

That should fix it, if it didn't create new app in react native  and make sure to follow these steps, worked for me after hours of searches.